# Circular array of (4, 6 or 12) interferometers with circumferential end points for GW analysis?

Tags: gravitational-waves, interferometry

If both or, at least, one of the two current LIGO installations instead of the single interferometer would have the circular array of (4, 6 or 12) interferometers (with circumferential locations of their end points) - would it provide more information, related to the characteristics of gravitational waves during their detection?

Comment: Perhaps, but an analysis would have to be performed. It is sufficient for detection to have orthogonal beams.   More information can be found here: https://www.advancedligo.mit.edu/summary.html

Comment: I imagine it'd help localize the cause of the disturbance, but I somewhat doubt any more information could be derived.

Answer (score 0):

It would make a small difference. The main difference would be probably some change, probably improvement, in the sensitivity and accuracies of measurements and parameters.

The best way to see it and understand it is to realize that detec isn't and measuring takes, at the basic level, two orthogonal(or really non-collinear) interferometers. If you have the sensitivity you can then re-construct what the wave would look like on any other two noncollinear interferometers.

So, what you gain with a circular array is the fact that you have multiple interferometers (remember, you detect nothing with one end of an interferometer, you need both ends), and you have to design the pairs optimally. With 12 mirrors at the circumference, and 12 interferometer detectors at the center, younhave 12 pairs, and you can then get an effective sensitivity and accuracy gains of sqrt(N). That is the basic number, sqrt(N), because that is the effective increase in SNR. That assumes the noise sources are un correlated among the 12 pairs.

I do not know if that's the case or not. If the noise is internal, and not interference, it would be. If outside interference it might be highly correlated.

Please also note that the math and analysis for this is not essentially different than if you were analyzing 12 circularly disposed pairs of radio interferometers. They've been built and used, arrays of interferometers for HF, microwave, and other frequencies, and the answer is well known. Weak gravitational waves are similar (not the same though) to electromagnetic waves, their polarizations are different but both have orthogonal polarizations, both are transversal, and two degrees of freedom. The biggest difference is tHe wavelengths, for Gravity Kms and for microwaves or radio meters or less. The wavelengths/the detection apparatus effective size might not be too different.

It seems to me w/o doing a little more analysis on the noise correlation one can not be sure. But certainly the improvement would not be any more than that For the arrangement the question described, and it might be less.